# Leaflet - more different icons on the map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I am currently using this library for my project

https://github.com/codersgyan/leaflet-store-locator

I want to add different icons for categories, like here
[image: categroy maps]

I added it to JSON, but I can't display the icon

```
{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [ xxxxx, xxxxxx]
        },
        "properties": {
          "name": "xxx",
          "city": "xxx",
          "address": "xxx",
    
           "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "https icon url",
            "iconSize": [55, 55],
            "iconAnchor": [50, 50],
            "popupAnchor": [-15, -50],
            "className": "dot"
        }
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a place in this code that needs to be changed:
[leaflet-store-locator](https://github.com/codersgyan/leaflet-store-locator/blob/a8dab506c6d5ca02e6d024d2fc442b93d3099683/app.js#L48)

```
var myIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'marker.png',
  iconSize: [30, 40]
});

const shopsLayer = L.geoJSON(storeList, {
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, { icon: myIcon });
  }
});
```

Instead of a globally set marker, you need to add it to the pointToLayer function.

```js
const shopsLayer = L.geoJSON(storeList, {
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

    // check what you have exactly in the 'feature'
    // console.log(feature);
    var myIcon = L.icon({     
      // I'm not sure of the path, that's why it's above console.log(feature);
      iconUrl: feature.properties.icon.iconUrl,
      iconSize: feature.properties.icon.iconSize, 
      // and here is the rest of the icon configuration
    }); 
    return L.marker(latlng, { icon: myIcon });
  }
});
```